# change md-card-title from app.component.html when card has its own component

Tags: angular, angular-material, interpolation, angular-material2

```
<app-card></app-card>
```

is in my app.component.html and displays the card component

```
<md-card class="card" style="box-shadow: none;">
<md-card-header>
  <md-card-title style="font-size:x-large;">
  </md-card-title>

</md-card-header>

<md-card-content>

  <p class="flow-text">
    {{placeholder}}  </p>
</md-card-content>
<md-card-actions>
  <button md-button>LIKE</button>
  <button md-button>SHARE</button>
</md-card-actions>
```

above is my card

I want to change the card title (ultimately also the content) without having the clutter of the card html code in my app.component.html .
I cant seem to figure out how I pass a string from my card.component.ts into my cards when having more than one string.

1. Card should have title {{title1}}
   2.nd card should have title {{title2}}

How do I use ngFor to repeat the number of cards displayed to the count of the strings in an array and therefore pass the string at which the index is into the card title?

Comment: So basically, you want to have the same cards repeated with a different title and content ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a component called card.component with:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({    
    selector: 'my-card',
    template:`
        <md-card class="card" style="box-shadow: none;">
         <md-card-header>
           <md-card-title style="font-size:x-large;">
            {{title}}
          </md-card-title>
         </md-card-header>    
        <md-card-content>
        <p class="flow-text">
          {{placeholder}}  </p>
       </md-card-content>
       <md-card-actions>
       <button md-button>LIKE</button>
       <button md-button>SHARE</button>
       </md-card-actions>
`

})

export class CardComponent{
    @Input() placeholder: string;
    @Input() title: string;
}
```

And finally to use it you just need:

```
<my-card [title] = "title" [placeholder] = "placeholder"></my-card>
```

Comment: Yeah that actually looks like it should work, but I get an odd error saying: 
    Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'CardComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like **@SergioEscudero** proposed in his answer, using an [Input component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding), and pass data from your parent to your child components using indexes like you though to.

A more optimal solution would be to use [Transclusion](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content) as well to create a Card component with dynamic content. This way, you can create your own custom content for each card, which will all have the same base as `CardComponent`